# The ParentDataWidget Flexible(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to apply if condition on the result of a retrieving query from Firebase real-time database. What I am trying to do is to tell flutter if a specific field of the result is equal to what I specified then and only then show the result.

I am getting this error as a result of running my code:
[Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lluNz.png)

and my code:

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        query: _dBRefAppt,
        itemBuilder: (
          BuildContext context,
          DataSnapshot snapShot,
          Animation<double> animation,
          int index,
        ) {
          if (snapShot.value['tutor_id'] == currentUId &&
              snapShot.value['status'] == 'accepted') {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(snapShot.value['date']),
              subtitle: new Text(snapShot.value['time']),
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        },
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

The problem is when I remove the if condition, the code works and shows all the results. How can I show only the results that I want. Any help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this:

```
 child: Flexible(
      flex: 1,
```

Use Flexible and Expanded only inside Rows, Columns and Flex widgets. Keep the if statement, it's not causing the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, the error is gone, but I still can't get the results, and I also get this (uid=10085(com.example.tutor_finder_app) 1.ui identical 1 line)

Comment: You can ignor the identical lines notice. But are you sure you don't have any spellingmistakes in your if statement? `tutor_id` for example, or post what you are getting and how it looks without it, and you db.

Comment: I check that very carefully, I solved the issue for now by returning an empty Text(''); I noticed whenever I remove return in else part or, return null the if part doesn't show.

Comment: somebody else on S.O. is showing, "wrap text with Flexible to get text to wrap".  So this answer makes that other one wrong?